# Using preprocessor directives to define command line options

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, c-preprocessor

If I wanted to add, let's say, a new .lib to the build only if a particular `#define` was set, how would I do that?

In the MSVC++ 2008 "Property Pages", you would simply add: `Config Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`, but I would like it if something like `#define COMPILE_WITH_DETOURS` was set, then the particular library would be added to the dependencies, otherwise it would be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set some linker options by using [`#pragma comment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7(v=VS.90).aspx?ppud=4) in one of your source files.

For example, to link against a 'detours.lib' library only if `COMPILE_WITH_DETOURS` is defined, you can use:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_WITH_DETOURS
#    pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
#endif
```

(this is specific to Microsoft Visual C++ and is not portable)